# Special characters (non-English) in Perl and HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, perl, character-encoding

I have text I am trying to display that is being sent from Perl to my web page. In Perl I have this set

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\n";
```

And I am pretty sure I need to change the charset setting. My first question is how can I change the setting to include more languages not to just change the language.

My second question is if I set the charset straight in Perl do I also need to change it on my HTML/JavaScript so that the web page the information is being 
displayed on displays it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

### Do not forget to decode and encode text based on source encoding!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ":all";
use Encode;

my $cgi = new CGI;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

print $cgi->header(-type    => 'text/html',
                   -charset => 'utf-8');

print $cgi->start_html(-title => 'Test',
                       -charset  => 'utf-8',
                       -encoding => 'utf-8',
                       -head => meta({-http_equiv => 'Content-Type',
                                      -content => 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}));

my $text = ...

Encode::from_to($text, 'latin1', 'utf8');

print $cgi->p($text);
print $cgi->end_html;
```

Comment: I agree with this answer except for the `Encode::from_to()` line. Why not be full utf8 and so encode the source data in utf8 too instead of converting it from Latin1?

Comment: @dolment - That line is an example how to change encoding, as data are read from other source that comes with some encoding. Certainly *latin1* has to be changed to whatever source encoding is.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is how can I change the setting to include more
>   languages

UTF-8 includes (almost) all languages.  Perhaps you mean "different encodings"?  In that case, you need to know what encoding your source is in.  Where did it come from **before** it passed through perl?

UTF-8 is also the predominant encoding online, and you're probably best to stick with it.  That means if you have a source that is not in utf8, you should use perl's decode() and encode() first.  But again: you do need to know what the source encoding is.

Comment: I am getting the data from the untappd json api. Its a beer website and a lot of the beer names are foreign and their characters not exactly showing up right

Comment: Have you asked them about this? http://help.untappd.com/  I would imagine they are using UTF-8 but...

Comment: I asked, but haven't heard back yet

Comment: If the Content-Type is set in the HTTP headers, it does not have to be set also in HTML (especially as the HTML trick applies only to HTML content). The true answer is stackoverflow's.